# The bullseye code coverage browser doesnot have all the source files?

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage, bullseye

I'm using bullseye code coverage to test the coverage in my mac machine, and built my application using it. When i opened the coverage browser, it has only few cpp files. Many are missing, which are actually the main files.

What is the reason for this? Am I doing anything wrong?

As far i know, I have configured it properly according to their included help files. While building I can see the bullseye compiler name, and moreover I'm getting a few files listed, so I think it is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im answering my own question, i found the problem, it was an option in xcode project settings which is "Generate Source As" which was set to objective c++ and hence it was not covered in bullseye as it will cover only pure c++